# Tuple with multiple numbers of arbitrary but equal type

Tags: python, types, tuples, type-hinting, python-typing

Currently, I am checking for tuples with multiple (e.g. three) numbers of arbitrary but equal type in the following form:

```py
from typing import Tuple, Union

Union[Tuple[int, int, int], Tuple[float, float, float]]
```

I want to make this check more generic, also allowing `numpy` number types. I.e. I tried to use `numbers.Number`:

```py
from numbers import Number
from typing import Tuple

Tuple[Number, Number, Number]
```

The above snipped also allows tuples of mixed types as long as everything is a number.

**I'd like to restrict the tuple to numbers of equal type.**

How can this be achieved?

---

Technically, this question applies to Python and the type hints specification itself. However, as pointed out in the comments, its handling is implementation specific, i.e. MyPy will not catch every edge case and/or inconsistency. Personally, I am using run-time checks with [typeguard](https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for testing and deactivate them entirely in production.

Comment: That's a bit tricky. I tried something with a `TypeVar` but then realized that `np.floating` and `np.integer` are floats/ints, i.e. `isinstance(np.float64(3), float) -> True`.

Comment: Even in your existing annotation, MyPy will sadly fail to raise an error if you pass in a tuple in which some items are floats and some are ints https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=49e79db53d21e231fa5c453fc399061d

Comment: @timgeb Numpy has a similar fundamental class like the regular Python standard library: `np.number`. Besides, a `numpy.float64` is - under most circumstances, depending on configuration, platform and compiler options (`sys.float_info`) - literally identical to a Python `float`, so this kind of thing would actually be ok for me.

Comment: @AlexWaygood Wow, that's impressive. Well, I am doing run-time checking, i.e. while my tests are running, I am using [typeguard](https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for verification instead of MyPy. It is able to catch this kind of inconsistencies.

Comment: I see. It might be good to edit that into your question — I assumed you were using your type hints for static analysis, as that's the most common use. I can't help you with respect to typeguard, as I don't have the package installed, and it sounds as though it interprets the semantics of type annotations somewhat differently to mypy et al.

Comment: @AlexWaygood I added a comment to the question as suggested. I hope it helps. Static analysis does not tell me everything I want to know. I am torturing my code with `pytest` and [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) plus run-time checks.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: @s-m-e Can you explain why `T = TypeVar('T', int, float); Tuple[T, T, T]` does not work for you? It should be equivalent to your "manual" versions `Tuple[int, int, int]` and `Tuple[float, float, float]`, so if these manual versions work for you, so should the `TypeVar` version.

Comment: @a_guest It does indeed work. I was not aware of `TypeVar`, to be honest. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `TypeVar` with `bound` argument. It allows restricting types to subtypes of a given type. In your case, the types should be the subtypes of `Number`:

```
from numbers import Number
from typing import TypeVar
 
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Number)
Tuple[T, T, T]
```

#### Why does it work?

`TypeVar` is a variable that allows to use a particular type several times in type signatures. The simplest example:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Tuple

T = TypeVar('T')
R = TypeVar('R')

def swap(x: T, y: R) -> Tuple[R, T]:
    return y, x
```

The static type checker will infer that arguments of the function `swap` should be the same as outputs in reversed order (note that return type T will be the same as the input type T).

Next, it might be useful to introduce restrictions for `TypeVar`. For instance, one could restrict values of a type variable to specific types: `TypeVar('T', int, str)`. In this answer, we use another kind of restriction with a keyword `bound` – it checks if the values of the type variable are subtypes of a given type (in our case, `Number`, which is a base class for all numerical types in Python).

More examples: [mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects) and [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects).

---

#### Working test:

```py
from numbers import Number
from typing import Tuple, TypeVar

import numpy as np
from typeguard import typechecked
 
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Number)

@typechecked
def foo(data: Tuple[T, T, T]):
    print('expected OK:', data)
    
for data in (
    (1, 2, 3), # ok
    (1.0, 2.0, 3.0), # ok
    (1, 2.0, 3), # TypeError
    (1.0, 2.0, 3), # TypeError
    (1.0, 2.0, np.float64(3.0)), # ok (yes!)
    (1, 2.0, np.float32(3)), # TypeError
    (1, 2.0, np.uint8(3)), # TypeError
):
    try:
        foo( data )
    except TypeError:
        print('expected TypeError:', data)
```