# Is it possible to type a list of tuples of identical generic types, with a static type checker?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Consider the following:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

class A(): pass
class B(A): pass
class C(A): pass


T = TypeVar("T", bound=A)


class Container(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(x: T):
        pass

b: Container[B] = Container(B())
c: Container[C] = Container(C())
```

How do I type-hint a function `foo` that will accept any list of tuples of identically typed containers:

```
foo([
    (b, b), 
    (c, c)
    ])
```

but refuse this (heterogeneous tuple):

```
foo([
    (c, b),  # tuples elements are not the same type
    (c, c)
    ])
```

I tried this:

```
ListOfSameContainerTuples = list[tuple[Container[T], Container[T]]]

def foo(containers: ListOfSameContainerTuples[T]):
    pass
```

but it doesn't work:

```
foo([
    (b, b), 
    (c, c)
    ])  
# error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "list[tuple[object, object]]"; 
# expected "list[tuple[Container[<nothing>], Container[<nothing>]]]"  [arg-type]

foo([
    (c, b), 
    (c, c)
    ])
# error: List item 0 has incompatible type "tuple[Container[C], Container[B]]"; expected "tuple[Container[C], Container[C]]"  [list-item]
```

The second error on mypy looks good, but I don't understand the first one:

- Why does mypy not know the type of `b` and `c` ?
- Why is my type signature `Container[<nothing>]` ?

I tried solutions from [Tuple with multiple numbers of arbitrary but equal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69254006/tuple-with-multiple-numbers-of-arbitrary-but-equal-type), to no avail.

Comment: Would you consider explicitly listing union variants to be an option? I.e. `list[tuple[Container[B], Container[B]] | tuple[Container[C], Container[C]]]`, which would pass type checking for the first and not the second

Comment: @Brian61354270 I'd prefer not to, because I want to make more subclasses of `A` later on

Comment: I'd advice to stop and identify your *real* requirements. For example, how is `class D(C): pass` different from `C`? I'd argue they are equivalent from typing perspective: you can use `D` everywhere where `C` is expected, thanks to LSP. `Callable[[D], Any]` will be more specific than `Callable[[C], Any]`, but you don't have anything contravariant here to consider. So, why should passing `[(D(), C())]` to your function be denied? The only corner case I can imagine is accessing `type(obj)` directly for direct comparison or `__name__` usage, but it's a corner case - just document or ignore it.

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike Thank you for your feedback, I understand what you mean. To get away from the toy example and closer to the real case, imagine `A` is a node class, and `(B(), B())` represents an edge between two `B` nodes. I was wondering if it was possible to type the list of edges to statically allow edges between B nodes only, between C nodes only, but disallow connections between B nodes and C nodes. I was wondering if there was a nice way to enforce it with types - but from your comment it seems like my reasonning isn't really translated in the types I defined.

Comment: @TrakJohnson Just a thought that comes to mind: you could mitigate LSP issues like what SUTerliakov mentioned by [disallowing your node classes from being subclassed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.final) and making `A` abstract. Then only instances of direct subclassess of `A` can exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a partial solution*, you can make the [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) `T` [covariant](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance):

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound=A, covariant=True)
```

Then

```py
foo([(b, b), (c, c)])
```

passes type checking with `mypy --strict` while

```py
foo([(c, b), (c, c)])
```

fails with the message

```
error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "foo"
```

---

<sup>*</sup>This works since when `T` is covariant, the type `tuple[Container[A], Container[A]]` is considered to be a supertype of both `tuple[Container[B], Container[B]]` and `tuple[Container[C], Container[C]]`. Prior to making `T` covariant, you type checker infered the expression

```
[(b, b), (c, c)]
```

as having type `tuple[object, object]`, because `object` was the only supertype common to both `tuple[Container[B], Container[B]]` and `tuple[Container[C], Container[C]]`. After making `T` covariant, that expression can instead be inferred  as having type `tuple[Container[A], Container[A]]`, which can bind with the parameter signature of `foo` by taking `T=A`.

The reason the mixed type case fails is a little more complicated, and still has some holes for mistakes. After making `T` covariant, your type checker infers the expression

```
(c, b), (c, c)
```

as having type

```
list[tuple[Container[C], Container[A]]]
```

This can't bind with the first parameter of `foo`, because even though `Container[A]` is a supertype of `Container[C]`, `tuple[Container[A], Container[A]]` **is not** `tuple[Container[C], Container[A]]`. You're type checker can't simply take `T=A` and call it a day as before.

The only way that call to `foo` passes type checking is if your type checker infers the type of the argument to be a list of homogeneous tuples, be it `tuple[Container[A], Container[A]]` or something more specific like `tuple[Container[B], Container[B]]` or `tuple[Container[C], Container[C]]`

Unfortunately, this approach relies your type checker picking a *specific* and *heterogeneous-tuple* type in order for the mixed arguments case to fail type checking. This could be problem, since if you construct a sufficiently varied argument list, it is possible that your type checker will not infer a specific heterogeneous-tuple type and instead will find `tuple[Container[A], Container[A]]` to be the most specific supertype.

For example, the expression

```
[(c, b), (b, c)]
```

will be inferred as having type

```
list[tuple[Container[A], Container[A]]]
```

so this argument *would* pass type checking if passed to `foo`.

---

**TL;DR:** when `T = TypeVar("T", bound=A)`, the code

```
reveal_type([(b, b), (b, b)])
reveal_type([(b, b), (c, c)])
reveal_type([(c, b), (c, c)])
reveal_type([(c, b), (b, c)])
```

will produce the `mypy`  output

```
Revealed type is "builtins.list[Tuple[Container[B], tmp.Container[tmp.B]]]"
Revealed type is "builtins.list[Tuple[builtins.object, builtins.object]]"
Revealed type is "builtins.list[Tuple[Container[C], builtins.object]]"
Revealed type is "builtins.list[Tuple[builtins.object, builtins.object]]"
```

But when `TypeVar("T", bound=A, covariant=True)`, it will produce the `mypy` output

```
Revealed type is "builtins.list[Tuple[Container[B], Container[B]]]"
Revealed type is "builtins.list[Tuple[Container[A], Container[A]]]"
Revealed type is "builtins.list[Tuple[Container[C], Container[A]]]"
Revealed type is "builtins.list[Tuple[Container[A], Container[A]]]"
```

Type checking will pass whenever the argument to `foo` is inferred to have a type of the form `list[tuple[Container[T], Container[T]]]` for a single substituted type `T`. Making `T` covariant makes that `True` for the example in the question (line #2, good!), but also makes it true for the maximally mixed case (line #4, bad!).

Comment: Thank you, looks good! What happens if I don't enable the `--strict` flag? Is it on by default?

Comment: @TrakJohnson [`--strict`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-strict) enables some optional error checks. It makes `mypy` more strict about what code passes type checking. If you don't enable `--strict`, mypy will be more lenient and let code pass type checking that would otherwise fail with `--strict` enabled

Comment: @TrakJohnson I edited my answer to further explain how inference is behaving here and to clarify the potential point of failure.

Comment: woah, thank you for the very detailed explanation! The last sentence of the TLDR makes me realize that the type annotation I put for `foo` doesn't work like I expected it to. If I understand it correctly, the type must be inferred for the whole list first, and then it is matched against `foo`'s annotation. However, what I want (not sure if that's possible at all) is for the type signature `tuple[Container[T], Container[T]]` to be "checked locally" on each element (and probably using `TypeVar("T", B, C)` instead of `bound=A`, to avoid being resolved with `A`). Do you think I can get any closer?

Comment: I haven't though of a way to come closer with static type checking yet. But if you'd be ok with runtime typechecking, I think [beartype](https://github.com/beartype/beartype) would be able to check this